# WP enqueue Google Maps API syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, roots-sage

I'm using the theme Sage from Roots.

```
/**
 * Theme assets
 */
function assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style('sage/css', Assets\asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, null);

  if (is_single() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
  }

  wp_enqueue_script('sage/js', Assets\asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('extras', Assets\asset_path('scripts/extras.js'), [], null, true);

  wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap' ), [], null, true);
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\assets', 100);
```

The first two instances of wp_enqueue_script work fine but after I added the google maps API, I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in
>   /srv/www/***/current/web/app/themes/*********/lib/setup.php on
>   line 106

Line 106 is the google maps line. Where is the extra comma? I know that it isn't a typo futher up/down in the script because if I remove the maps API part, it works as expected.

Comment: your `(` and `)` don't match up at that line

Comment: How did I not see that...  lol :O Please add as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap' ), [], null, true);
```

Your brackets don't match up